# Vue.js Transition of data based on array index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

In my project, I must use array to display content, and on click update it with next entry of the array.

I don't know how can I use vue.js Transition tag to make an animation when my array index is updated. I would like the content disappear, then change with new data, then make appear new content. Is it possible to do it with this tag or I must make my own function?

Here is a basic exemple.

```
<div @click="activeValue++">+1</div>

<transition mode="out-in" name="fade">
    <div>{{myArray[activeValue].title}}</div>
</transition>
```

```
data() {
        return {
            activeValue: 0,
            myArray: [
                {
                    title: "Title 1",
                    content: "Lorem impsum",
                },
                {
                    title: "Title 2",
                    content: "Lorem impsum",
                },
                {
                    title: "Title 3",
                    content: "Lorem impsum",
                },
            ]
        }
    },
```

```
// Basic vue.js transition
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `key` in div will help transition to distinguish there is a different in div when activeValue change

```
<div :key="activeValue">
   {{ myArray[activeValue].title }}
</div>
```

Here is the codesandbox for your reference:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-dubinsky-ruztq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

P.S. Please handle `activeValue++` larger than 2 (which mean more than 3 items

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [Vue Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components):

> Vue provides a transition wrapper component, allowing you to add
> entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the
> following contexts:
>
> - Conditional rendering (using **v-if**)
> - Conditional display (using **v-show**)
> - Dynamic components
> - Component root nodes

That said, the `Transition` tag needs the DOM element to be rendered/unrendered, conditionally, in order to let the transition take place. Here is a [CodeSandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-rgb-1jvfc?file=/src/App.vue) that you can try with.